# Extract a particular keyword from string using regexp_substr in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have several strings in column `Phone_mid_bsnl_AC_10035` and I want to extract the code next to AC that is 10035.

I used this SQL code:

```sql
WITH CTE(STR) AS 
(
    SELECT 'Phone_mid_bsnl_AC_10035' 
    FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '[^_]+', 1, 5) 
FROM CTE
```

It does give the code but it is not necessary in some of the strings that the code is present at the 5 position. Like in this string `Phone_up_gsk_pdp_AC_90054` it is present in the 6 position. Is there a way to use the reg_exp to get only the digits after matching AC. The code will always be of 5 digits.

Comment: Is that *numeric value* always at the end of the string? Or could it be anywhere else, but it always follows the AC?

Comment: yes it always would be present after 'AC_' and based on the values of the column so far, it is at the end of the string only

Comment: Right; then code you're interested in can be simplified. There are several answers there already, pick the one you find the most appropriate.  `regexp_substr(source_value, '\d+$')` seems to be the simplest (from my point of view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also can be done using `regexp_replace`

```
WITH CTE(STR) AS (
SELECT 'Phone_mid_bsnl_AC_10035' FROM DUAL union all
SELECT 'Phone_AC_10036_something' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT regexp_replace(STR, '.*AC_([0-9]{5}).*','\1') FROM CTE
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/tow-uY62)

Comment: What does the second parameter in the expression regexp_replace(STR, '.*AC_([0-9]{5}).*','\1') that is '\1' indicate?

Comment: It extract the first captured group which is in this case `([0-9]{5})`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '_(\d{5})(_|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) FROM CTE
```

instead. It will extract first occurence of 5 digits between `_` and `_` or end of the string.

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hJmFxDJD).

```sql
WITH CTE(STR) AS (
SELECT 'Phone_mid_bsnl_A_C_10035' FROM DUAL union all
  SELECT 'Phone_mid_bsnl_AC_10035' FROM DUAL union all
  SELECT 'Phone_up_gsk_pdp_AC_90054' FROM DUAL union all
  SELECT 'Phone_mid_bsnl_A_C_10035_sad' FROM DUAL union all
  SELECT 'Phone_mid_bsnl_A_C_1003' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, '_(\d{5})(_|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) a FROM CTE
```

| a |
| --- |
| 10035 |
| 10035 |
| 90054 |
| 10035 |
| null |

Answer (score 0):

If numeric value is always at the end of a string, then you could simplify it to

sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Phone_mid_bsnl_AC_10035' from dual)
```

Query:

```
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, '_', -1) + 1) result_1,
  4         regexp_substr(col, '\d+$') result_2
  5  from test;

RESULT_1   RESULT_2
---------- ----------
10035      10035

SQL>
```

- `result_1`: returns string that follows the last underline character
- `result_2`: returns numeric string "anchored" to the end of the source string